# Trace egg-info from renamed reallocated python package

Tags: python, egg, distribute

Using

pip install django-compressor

I can install this app, it gets unpackaged in /lib/whatever/compressor

and there is a /lib/django_compressor-1.1.2.egg-info. By looking at file inside the egg-info: 
top_level.txt I can see that package is at top level with a new name.

What about if I wan't to get the egg-info for compressor, the reverse operation? I had search throug distribute and found nothing.

in fact, what I'm trying to achieve is tracing lot's of python packages outside the egg and renamed, so is not just the case of compressor.

thanks